# How to use jar to dll converting result?

Tags: android, ikvm

I'm trying to convert *.jar to *.dll and using this into my android project

1. download ikvm-7.2.4630.5
2. run> ikvmc.exe -out:some.dll some.jar
3. after many warnings I got some.dll
4. create android project and reference some.dll
5. First Error: The type 'java.lang.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'IKVM.OpenJDK.Core, Version=7.2.4630.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58'.
6. Add to project IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll
7. build it
8. Second Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'IKVM.Runtime, Version=7.2.4630.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Add IKVM.RunTime.dll to the project.  It should be in the same /bin folder as IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll

I got the same error when I tried to do this!  Thanks for the methodical step-through.

Hopefully you already found an answer though!